# Contact Fisherman Guesthouse in Penang

Tags: malaysia, lost-luggage

I have to contact the Fisherman Village Guesthouse in Teluk Bahang, Penang.

Unfortunately, I can not find their phone number or email anywhere. Can someone help me?

(I stupidly forgot a bag there)

Comment: [tripadvisor- 04-8852084](https://www.tripadvisor.jp/Restaurant_Review-g660694-d2039716-Reviews-Fishing_Village_Seafood-Penang_Island_Penang.html)

Comment: @Dhina This is an unrelated business. I phoned tham, as it is nearby, but they couldn't help me :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Their phone is in the Lonely Planet for Malaysia - it's (604) 885-2936.  The first three numbers are the country code and the area code for Penang, if you're calling from outside the country.  Here's the [source](https://books.google.co.th/books?id=VMKOuzRxOJsC&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq=teluk%20bahang%20guesthouse%20fisherman%20village&source=bl&ots=GI0wjEnpbc&sig=7FvHBA4u4RNXyc33c5JAYScw89Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNyJKPsafLAhUWBI4KHdrLD5wQ6AEIUTAG#v=onepage&q=teluk%20bahang%20guesthouse%20fisherman%20village&f=false).  Good luck getting your stuff back!

Comment: Unfortunatly, This number do not answer :-(